# Removing a control from Windows Form and adjusting other controls to fit

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form App that I can add user controls to by clicking a button. 
I can also delete one control at a time by selecting it and clicking a delete button.
All that works fine but if I add three controls and delete the second there is an gap between the two remaining controls on the form. I would like to have all the remaining controls move up to fill in the gap.

Like this:

//Add three controls and we have this:
Control1
Control2
Control3

//Delete Control2 and we now have this:
Control1

Control3

//What I would like is this:
Control1
Control3

Here is what I have tried but it isn't doing the job

```
private void btQuestionDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool adjustMode = false;
    int height = 0;

    foreach (Control c in this.tpQuestions.Controls)
    {
        if (c is QuestionControl)
        {
            if (adjustMode)
            {
                int moveUpBy = c.Top - height;
                c.Top = moveUpBy;
                c.Parent.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                QuestionControl q = (QuestionControl)c;
                if (q.IsSelected)
                {
                    this.tpQuestions.Controls.Remove(c);
                    adjustMode = true;
                    height = q.Height;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you want to have a look at flowLayoutPanels ?

Comment: Thanks. Adding and removing the controls from the FlowLayoutPanel makes life much easier. If you put your comment as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you want to have a look at flowLayoutPanels ?

Answer (score 0):

To add a control just do this:

```
public void AddControl(ControlToAdd item)
{
    item.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

    this.Controls.Add(item);
}
```

To remove a control just `Dispose` it! All remaining controls will slide up!